# Spring AOP Proxy Issues while using Pointcut with javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..)

Tags: java, spring, websphere, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am trying to set **ClientIdentifier** value by invoking **DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('XXXX')** procedure after getting DB connection. To implement this I have used **Spring AOP aspects** as explained in link:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html
below is the piece of code which I have:

```
@Aspect
public class ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer {

@AfterReturning(pointcut= "execution(* javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))",
        returning = "connection")
public Connection setClientIdentifier(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement cs=connection.prepareCall("{call DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('XXXX')}");
    cs.execute();
    cs.close();
    return connection;
```

I have configured **aop autoaspect proxy** in spring configuration xml file.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="connectionPreparer" 
    class="xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer" />
```

I am Unsing **web sphere application server** to deploy application and I have configured data source as specified in link : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tspr_config_data_access.html
When I deploy my application I am getting below error. seems Spring incorrectly trying to cast/subclass which is final and getting issues with cglib proxies. If I use other connection pool providers **datasource** configurations instead of **web sphere JNDI datasource** evrything seems to be working fine. I have tried with **org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource** and I am able to set client identifier value successfully. 
below is the error I am getting with web sphere JNDI datasource:

```
    DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'sessionFactory'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'sessionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0'
DEBUG - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'dataSource' with 0 common interceptors and 2 specific interceptors
DEBUG - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134@df1d109a]
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.equals(java.lang.Object)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.hashCode()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.toString()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isPreFiltered()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.io.PrintWriter com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getLogWriter() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isProxyTargetClass()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isFrozen()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setLogWriter(java.io.PrintWriter) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Object com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.unwrap(java.lang.Class) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setExposeProxy(boolean)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.indexOf(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getTargetClass()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.aop.TargetSource com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getTargetSource()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getLoginTimeout() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvisor(int,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isExposeProxy()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.sql.Connection com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getConnection() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvice(int,org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setLoginTimeout(int) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Class[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getProxiedInterfaces()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.sql.Connection com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.indexOf(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setPreFiltered(boolean)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.replaceAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.aop.Advisor[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getAdvisors()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.util.logging.Logger com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getParentLogger() throws java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.toProxyConfigString()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
DEBUG - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#ca01323a': [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0]
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@184af104: 
defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,transitionController,dataSource,
sessionFactory,transactionManager,persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor,
org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,
pointCut,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; 
root of factory hierarchy
Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#c0432d95': [(inner bean)#ca01323a]
 ERROR - Context initialization failed
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [sessionfactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:494)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:379)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:164)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 151 more
```

I also tried to use **proxy target= true and false** to force proxies to be created with JDK dynamic proxies instead of cglib. but in both ways it is using cglib proxies.

has anyone seen these kind of errors. Can someone please look at the error and let me know if there are any other alternative solutions that I can follow to resolve this error.

UPDATE: 
Adding JNDI configuration.
I have defined resource-ref in web.xml file

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/springdbres-ref-name>jdbc/myDS>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSourceres-type>javax.sql.DataSource>
<res-auth>Containerres-auth>Container>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareableres-sharing-scope>Shareable>
</resource-ref>
```

and i have defined data source bean and jndi look up configurations as below:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id=" dataSource"
    jndi-name="jdbc/myDS"
    cache="true"
    resource-ref="true"
    lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Comment: Add the jndi lookup for the datasource. Also if IBM already made the class final it won't work at least not with glib proxies.

Comment: Thank you. Do you want me to update the question with jndi look up configuration. I already have that configuration in application I just didnt specifi the whole here. Which IBM class you are referring to here?

Comment: That is what I requested for, so yes I want you to update the question.

Comment: I have already specified it in question. I have followed the configuration specified as in link http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tspr_config_data_access.html

Comment: There is no jndi configuration (`<jndi:lookup .. />` or related) in your configuration. So again please add it.

Comment: I have updated question with JNDI configuration.

Comment: The problem is your JNDI configuration. Due to the `lookupOnStartup=false` (on either config) a proxy is being created. This leads to proxying a proxy and leads to the behavior you see. I suspect it would work if you set it to `true` it starts to work as then there is no more proxy in play. A solution don't use AOP but simply use a wrapper around the datasource that does what you want.

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/interchangeds"></property>
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />

Comment: This time i set it to lookupOnStartup="true" it still give me the same above error.

Comment: Remove the `proxyInterface` as well next to that the one you changed is useless as it is overriden by `jee:jndi-lookup`.

Comment: @Denium..I have tried it in multiple ways but still I am not able to resolve this issue. From your previous comment I see that "A solution don't use AOP but simply use a wrapper around the datasource that does what you want." ..Could you please point me in a roight direction to have wrapper for data source instead of Spring AOP, Any sample configuration or code would be helpful for me to write a wrapper for datasource to resolve this issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You just create a class which implements `DataSource` and delegates all methods to another `DataSource`. Then in the `getConnection` method you just add the behavior you want/need before (or after depending on your needs) calling the delegate.

Comment: I've created a DatasourceWrapper which implements javax.sql.datasource and injected datasource as bean.Everytime I invoke a service method which is annotated with @Transactional, control comes to getConnection in datasourcewrapper which inturn calls ds.getConnection(), under that line I've logic to set clientIdentifier, but once it invokes ds.getConnection() control is not coming to wrapper class to execute the line which has logic to set clientidentifier. Only time I see that statement executed is when I deploy application but not every time I invoke service method to perform DB operation.

Comment: You should also use the wrapper anywhere you use a datasource, so instead of injecting the one from JNDI you need to inject your wrapper.